# Google Cloud Identity setup blocked by use of google analytics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to setup Google Cloud Identity to work with GCP. However I'm being blocked from registering my business domain name as it "is already being used by another Google service", in this case Google Analytics and adwords.

Has anyone come across this and how to get round it?

Cheers
Duncan

Comment: Are your logins for GCP different than Google Analytics / Adwords? Try using, or add the same one used for the other services to your GCP account. I have multiple Google accounts and services and I had to use the same account login to be able to use them all at the same time. Maybe this tip will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe this could be a confusion and that domain belong to you, you can raise a [ticket](https://gsuite.google.com/support/) to the  Gsuite team, they should help you